# Problem About Calculation of double Higgs production Cross Section (for gluon fusion) with FeynArts+FormCalc

Tags: computational-physics, feynman-diagrams, higgs, large-hadron-collider, scattering-cross-section

I want to mention about my problem about FeynArts/FormCalc.I have tried to calculate LHC cross section for "gluon gluon -> H H" process at Standard Model. However, my result XS is quite different from the ones in the literature. I have no idea about this difference or where is the problem.  I'm using  FeynArts 3.9, FormCalc 9.3 and LoopTools 2.13. I attached the my FeynArts mathematica file.

In literature

XS(gluon gluon -> H H at 14 TeV at LHC)=~0,033 pb

but it is ~0,95 pb in my result.

Could you give me some suggestions? Please, check my mathematica file. Is there any mistakes or missing in my codes.

Thank you very much

> << FeynArts.m
>
> << FormCalc.m
>
> $InitialDirectory; 
> name = "glglHH-SM" process = {V[5], V[5]} -> {S[1],
> > S[1]}; SetOptions[InsertFields, Model -> "SMQCD",    InsertionLevel ->
> > {Particles},    ExcludeFieldPoints -> {FieldPoint[0][V[5], V[5],
> > V[5]]}]; $PaintSE = MkDir[name <> ".diagrams"]; DoPaint[diags_, file_,
>   opt___] :=   Paint[diags, opt,    DisplayFunction -> (Export[
>         ToFileName[$PaintSE, file <> ".ps"], #] &)]
>
> tops = CreateTopologies[0, 2 -> 2]; ins = InsertFields[tops, process];
>   DoPaint[ins, "born"]; born = CalcFeynAmp[CreateFeynAmp[ins]]
>
> Print["Counter terms"]
>
> tops = CreateCTTopologies[1, 2 -> 2,     ExcludeTopologies ->
>   {TadpoleCTs, WFCorrectionCTs}]; ins = InsertFields[tops, process];
>   DoPaint[ins, "counter"]; counter = CalcFeynAmp[CreateFeynAmp[ins]]
>
> Print["Self energies"]
>
> tops = CreateTopologies[1, 2 -> 2, SelfEnergiesOnly]; ins =
>   InsertFields[tops, process]; DoPaint[ins, "self"]; self =
>   CalcFeynAmp[CreateFeynAmp[ins]]
>
> Print["Vertices"]
>
> tops = CreateTopologies[1, 2 -> 2, TrianglesOnly]; ins =
>   InsertFields[tops, process,     ExcludeParticles -> {F[3 | 4, {1 |
>   2}]}]; DoPaint[ins, "vert"]; vert = CalcFeynAmp[CreateFeynAmp[ins]];
>
> Paint[ins]
>
> Print["Boxes"]
>
> tops = CreateTopologies[1, 2 -> 2, BoxesOnly]; 
>   ins = InsertFields[tops, process, 
>       ExcludeParticles -> {F[3 | 4, {1 | 2}]}]; DoPaint[ins, "box"]; box = CalcFeynAmp[CreateFeynAmp[ins]];
>
> Paint[ins]
>
> col = ColourME[All, born]
>
> amps = {born, self, vert, box};
>
> {born, self, vert, box} =    Abbreviate[amps, 6,     Preprocess ->
>   OnSize[100, Simplify, 500, DenCollect]];
>
> abbr = OptimizeAbbr[Abbr[]];
>
> subexpr = OptimizeAbbr[Subexpr[]];
>
> dir = SetupCodeDir[name <> ".fortran"]
>
> WriteSquaredME[born, {self, vert, box}, col, abbr, subexpr,
>   LoopSquare -> True, dir]
>
> WriteRenConst[amps, dir]